# SlidingMenu(jfeinstein) - How to control secondary sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I am using jfenstein's sliding menu lib. But I need to control two sliding menus separately. Sometimes second has to be disabled.And sometimes first slidingmenu has to be disabled.

When I have used menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN); both of them effected.

This my code :

```
        menu = new SlidingMenu(activity);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.sliding_menu_shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_frame);

        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

        SlidingMenuListFragment slidingMenuListFragment = new SlidingMenuListFragment();
        slidingMenuListFragment.setMenuBuilder(this);

        /*
         * left menu
         */
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.sliding_menu_frame, slidingMenuListFragment)
        .commit();



        /*
         * right menu
         */
        SlidingMenuListFragment rightMenu = new SlidingMenuListFragment();
        rightMenu.setMenuBuilder(this);
        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_frame);
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.sliding_menu_frame, rightMenu )
        .commit();
```

Comment: What is your exact question? I guess you want to control one or the other - did you try to use SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I fix it with the following :

```
//can open left and right panel
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

//can only open left panel and show only left (perhaps overlay the right panel ?) 
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
```

but it only works to "disable/make invisible" the right panel
if you do :

```
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

it only show the left panel on the right.