# SlidingMenu(jfeinstein). Disable secondary menu only

Tags: android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

Is it possible to disable only secondary Menu in SlidingMenu lib?

When I use this:

```
mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
```

it disables both menus.

Update:

```
mSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
mSlidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_left);
mSlidingMenu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_right);
```

Comment: You want to disable only one menu if it's LEFT and RIGHT menu, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I want to control them separately.

Comment: What do you mean by Secondary menu?

Comment: A similar question has been asked but I'm afraid it has no answer given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249669/slidingmenujfeinstein-how-to-control-secondary-sliding-menu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but it works for me.

```
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
setupRightMenu();
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);

// to enable right menu
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

// to disable right menu
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on cpalasanu response so I create a new response :

Changing the mode works in some case because in this configuration you just overlay the right panel with the left panel when you set : sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);